# Python Postgres - How to create arrays for single columns?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a Postgres Table with 72 Columns, each of them has 300 rows in it (most of them are decimal numbers)
Example:
Sensor1|Sensor2|Sensor3.....Sensor72
1...
2...
3...
.
.
.
300

How I am able to put single columns in different arrays?
What I am going to do with it is to do math. operations and plot them after.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the table into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user@localhost:5432/mydb')
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "My_Table"', con=engine)
```

and then use pandas to do data analysis and manipulation.

Comment: Thank you very much! i will try it out! :)